# Determining the image by a complex function $f(z)$ of numbers lying on a curve

Tags: complex-analysis

How do I determine the image of the function $f(z) = z^4$ on a set of complex numbers lying on a curve that has been given to me?

The equation of the curve in question is : $\cos(t)+i\sin(t)$ for $t$ between $0$ and $1$ inclusively.

Comment: Give the curve that you were given.

Comment: It looks only a matter of separation of real and imaginary part...

Comment: Hint: $(\cos t + i \sin t)^4 = (e^{it})^4 = e^{i4t} = ???$

Comment: @achillehui the thing is I don't even know where to start with this sort of question

Comment: @logarithm done

Comment: @JeanMarie mind walking me through as I'm completely clueless ?

Answer (score 2):

The answer by @logarithm is exact.

An equivalent way is that given by achille hui by working on complex exponentials.

Let me say it still in a different way.

The initial set of points is a rather small arc of the unit circle (from $(1,0)$ to $(\sin(1),\cos(1))=(0.54,0.84)$. Such points = complex numbers, when set to the power $4$,

- have their module **set to power $4$**, but it was equal to $1$, thus it remains $1$, and
- have their argument **multiplied by $4$**.

This is why, finally, you get an arc of the unit circle four times longer than the initial one, ranging from $(1,0)$ to $(\sin(4),\cos(4))=(-0.65,-0.76)$ (taken in the direct orientation).

Answer (score 1):

You need to compute the image of $[0,1]$ by the composition of $f(z)=z^4$ and $g(t)=cos(t)+i\sin(t)$.

Compose them $$f(g(t))=(\cos(t)+i\sin(t))=\cos(4t)+i\sin(4t)$$

where the last equation is due to [De Moivre's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Moivre%27s_formula).

Now determine the location of these points. Note that the absolute value of these points is $1$, since $\cos^2(4t)+\sin^2(4t)=1$. Their argument is $4t$ since $\tan(4t)$ is the quotient of their imaginary part ($\sin(4t)$) divided by their real part ($\cos(4t)$).

Therefore, these are points that are at distance $1$ from the origin and angle ranging, since $t$ ranges from $0$ to $1$, from $0$ to $4$ radians.

$4$ radians is larger than $\pi$, but smaller than $3\pi/2$. Therefore, it is an arc larger than half the circle but smaller than $3/4$ of a circle.